# Android Recall Service

Tags: android

If i am in an activity i call a service b using the following code:

```
String start = "start";
    Intent i = new Intent(QScheduleActivity.this, UploadService.class);
    i.putExtra("start", start);
    startService(i)
```

Once i am inside this service, how do i recall the service from within the service if i need to?

Inside the else i am trying to recall the service like this:

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        String start = "start";
        Intent i = new Intent(UploadService.this, UploadService.class);
        i.putExtra("start", start);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

Comment: Hope i explained correctly..I want to go inside the UploadService.class and this checks if there is internet connectivity and then uploads a file to the server, but if there is no internet connectivity i want to put inside the else statement to recall itself...so the recall will keep happening until there is internet connectivity and the files are uploaded

Comment: Hmmmmm also if someone knows a way to maybe wait 30 minutes before it checks internet connectivity as i know this will drain battery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Inside the else i am trying to recall the service like this:

You are asking for a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent`. If your goal is to have the alarm call `startService()`, you should be using a `getService()` `PendingIntent`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class. I think it provides the functionality you need, though perhaps not in quite the way you're describing it.

From the documentation:

> This class provides access to the
>   system alarm services. These allow you
>   to schedule your application to be run
>   at some point in the future. When an
>   alarm goes off, the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) that had
>   been registered for it is broadcast by
>   the system, automatically starting the
>   target application if it is not
>   already running. Registered alarms are
>   retained while the device is asleep
>   (and can optionally wake the device up
>   if they go off during that time), but
>   will be cleared if it is turned off
>   and rebooted.

Comment: Yeh I have tried that but doesn't seem to work, i was thinking maybe i am not calling the service correctly...or maybe its an issue recalling the service from within the service

Comment: I suggest you post another question about using the AlarmManager, including the code that you're using with it.

Comment: I have added it to this, but my first issue is just to call the service from within the service

Comment: @Usmaan: What I think you want to do is to create your FileUploader service so that it *always* runs in response to an Alarm. The first alarm would run immediately, so that there's no delay in uploading the file if you already have connectivity. If the upload fails, you then set another alarm to try again in 30 minutes. (There are other ways to create this functionality, but this approach strikes me as the simplest.)